# Parsing JSON ARRAY in Java: Java code + correct import + Url (link) to download the JAR

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, jar

I need to write a code to Parsing JSON ARRAY in Java.

Please give me:

1) Java code

2) correct import of corresponding jar library

3) Url (link) to download the JAR

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;





public static <T> T jsonStringToObject(String jsonString , Class<T> objectClass){

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            T t=null;
            try {
                  t = mapper.readValue(jsonString, objectClass);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return t;
        }



Person person=jsonStringToObject(jsonString, Person.class);
```

//note person call have same property as of json

download jacson-core jar from here
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomfasterxmljacksoncorejar.htm